# Problema em Asset de WebBrowser

Tags: c#, unity3d, plugin

Olá, estou com problema num Asset que adquiri recentemente, onde acusa um problema chamado SharedPluginServe.exe, ele é um Asset que permite a navegação pela internet através da Unity, o problema ocorre enquanto o navegador é carregado, mas apos ele carregar, eu reparei que o sistema para de acusar o erro, abaixo segue alguns Prints...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Parece ser um erro no plugin. Como o plugin é essencialmente uma DLL externa à Unity, eu sugiro vc postar essa dúvida lá no fórum da asset que comprou, na Asset Store...

Comment: Tudo bem, muito obrigado.